# Writing an equals() method for Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, boolean

Im doing an inheritance question and I have everything completed except the Boolean part. My code will compile, but when comparing the name, birthday, and ssn, it will only come out as false.

For example, I inputted:

- Jim
- 6 30 2001
- 123456789
- Jim
- 6 30 2001
- 123456789

The output will be false.

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private Date birthday;
    private int ssn;


    public Person(String name, Date birthday, int ssn)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getBirthday()
    {
        return birthday;
    }


    public int getSSN()
    {
        return ssn;
    }
     /* I already called a dates toString() method for birthday */
    public String toString() 
    {
        return name + " has birthday " +  birthday  + " and SSN " + ssn;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object otherObj)
    {
        if(otherObj == null)
            return false;
        else if(otherObj.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;
        else
        {
            Person otherP = (Person)otherObj;
            if(otherP.name.equals(this.name) &&
            otherP.birthday == this.birthday &&
            otherP.ssn == this.ssn)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `==` to compare the birthdays? In general you'd want to use `.equals` to  compare objects.

Comment: Where is inheritance?

Comment: Always, when overwriting `equals` you should also overwrite `hashCode`. Otherwise many classes like `HashSet` (that use `hashCode`) won't work as expected. If you work with an **IDE** you should take a look for an option to **generate** `equals` and `hashCode`. The generated code will probably work better than your selfwritten stuff.

Comment: oh I see! I was made to believe I had to only use .equals for Strings only, thank you!

Comment: The reason why `equals` should be used for `String` holds for **any object**. `==` only compares for **identity** whereas `equals` often compares the **content/properties**.

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you don’t use the long outdated `Date` class for birthday. The modern `java.time.LocalDate` is both nicer to work with and matches your requirement of a date without hour-of-day more precisely.

Comment: It may work with `!=` for comparing the return values from `getClass()`, but here too I would prefer `.equals()`.

Comment: As mentioned, the troublesome `Date` class is now legacy, and should be avoided. Supplanted by the java.time classes, specifically [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Convert by calling `Date.toInstant()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inheritance here. In fact, writing equals method while inheriting from a superclass brings up a whole different discussion around class design (prefer composition over inheritance) .

In this case, I think you need to follow the rule of thumb, that is to always use equals method for logical comparison of all fields. == checks are for identity comparison and very seldom can work for logical equality (for example enums)

Another point to note is that your class will misbehave with datastructures that use hashing.

This topic is covered in good detail in chapter 3 of Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here:

```
if(otherP.name.equals(this.name) &&
        otherP.birthday == this.birthday &&
        otherP.ssn == this.ssn)
```

The code above is your main code for checking whether or not two `Person` objects are equal. You say your issue occurs when you supply two objects with the exact same birthdays, names, and SSNs. I'm not sure how your input code is creating the objects, but from what I can tell it's probably creating a new Date for every birthday.

There is an important difference between the `==` operator and the `equals` method. A variable of any type contains a value. For primitive data types (e.g. `int`), the value of the variable is the value it's actually storing. However, for an object variable (e.g. `String`, `Date`) the value is actually a reference to an object. If two object variables refer to the same object on the heap, they will have the same value; if they refer to different objects on the heap, they will have different values.

The `==` operator just checks the value of the variable, nothing else. When using it with primitives, it checks to see if the values stored in the variables are the same, which is proper because the values are stored directly. When using it with object variables, it checks to see if the two variables refer to the same object on the heap. Since the values of the variables are in fact references, this is the result when you check if the two values, or references, are the same.

The `equals` method, on the other hand, actually (is supposed to) go check further if two objects are considered equal, in that their states are the same. For example, it can check if two `Date` objects represent the same date. Java cannot magically tell if two different objects are equal - the class has to implement the `equals` method itself. (Otherwise, it resorts to a default implementation where it just checks the references.)

In your code sample above, you are using the `==` operator properly on the primitive `ssn` (since it is a primitive), and the `equals` method properly on the object `name` (since the references in each `Person` could be different, but represent the same string). However, you are using the `==` operator on the object variable `birthday`, which simply checks if the two `Person` objects being compared have the same `Date` object. Likely, since your calling code is just creating a new `Date` object on each input, the check fails because the two `Person` objects have two different objects for `birthday`. Just change that to an `equals` method call and your code should work.